# Grouped UITableView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Often I see layouts on the iPhone like the one I attached.[image]

How is this done best? With Interface builder or programmatically? How do i add a subview to the UITableView without occluding the actual table cells (i.e how do i set a margin to have space for subviews)?

Using Xcode4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tableView has a header and footer and every section has those too.

to set the tableview's hear and footer (in my screenshot green), do:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView: headerView];
[self.tableView setTableFooterView: footerView];
```

for header and footer for sections (blue), youl'll have to implement

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

[image: screenshot]

The code of the shown program you'll find at [github](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/MyContacts)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done with the `tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView` properties of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

The non-cell areas are usually done as section header and footer views.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best would be to use interface builder. You can use interface builder to connect all of the actions to your code visually.

You can also use interface builder to change the positioning of the subview.

I hope this helps!