# UITableView tableFooterView not appearing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` to which I add a `tableFooterView`, for some reason the `tableFooterView` is not appearing?

How I add my `tableFooterView`

I add the `tableFooterView` in a `connectionDidFinishLoading` method after reloading the `tableview` data.

So what I do is

```
[controls reloadData];

UIView *myFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
if(self.item.canRunOnDemand)
{
    UIButton *buttonRunWorkflow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [buttonRunWorkflow addTarget:self action:@selector(runWorkflow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [buttonRunWorkflow setTitle:@"Run Now" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonRunWorkflow.frame = CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, 44); 
    buttonRunWorkflow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [buttonRunWorkflow setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myFooterView addSubview:buttonRunWorkflow];
}
if(item.canRunAlways)
{
    UILabel *canRunAlwaysLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 46, 100, 44)];
    canRunAlwaysLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    canRunAlwaysLabel.text = @"Run Always:";
    UISwitch *canRunAlways = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 56, 100, 44)];
    [canRunAlways addTarget:self action:@selector(canRunAlwaysChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [myFooterView addSubview:canRunAlways];
    [myFooterView addSubview:canRunAlwaysLabel];
    [canRunAlwaysLabel release];
    [canRunAlways release];
}

[myFooterView release];

[controls.tableFooterView addSubview:myFooterView];
```

Footer view height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == [[fields objectAtIndex:section] count] - 1)
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == [[fields objectAtIndex:section] count] - 1)
    {
        UIView *myFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
        if(self.item.canRunOnDemand)
        {
            UIButton *buttonRunWorkflow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [buttonRunWorkflow addTarget:self action:@selector(runWorkflow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [buttonRunWorkflow setTitle:@"Run Now" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            buttonRunWorkflow.frame = CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, 44); 
            buttonRunWorkflow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [buttonRunWorkflow setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myFooterView addSubview:buttonRunWorkflow];
        }
        if(item.canRunAlways)
        {
            UILabel *canRunAlwaysLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 46, 100, 44)];
            canRunAlwaysLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            canRunAlwaysLabel.text = @"Run Always:";
            UISwitch *canRunAlways = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 56, 100, 44)];
            [canRunAlways addTarget:self action:@selector(canRunAlwaysChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [myFooterView addSubview:canRunAlways];
            [myFooterView addSubview:canRunAlwaysLabel];
            [canRunAlwaysLabel release];
            [canRunAlways release];
        }
        return myFooterView;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you have the correct height for your footer? heightForFooterInSection.....

Comment: yes I am sure, I set it as follows

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021315/grouped-uitableview-subviews/9021898#9021898 I also added some sample project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By looking at the header file of `UITableView.h` we see the declaration of property `tableFooterView` like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableFooterView; // accessory view below content. default is nil. not to be confused with section footer
```

so the default `property` is `nil`. That's why you can't add another `UIView` to nil `UIView`. 
You should do something like this:

```
controls.tableFooterView = myFooterView;
```

Answer (score -4):

Are you trying to add footer view in table view?
If you are trying for that Implement your footer view in this method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

This may helps you.Thanks!!

Comment: But what happens when the table is empty?

Comment: You're confusing "section footer views" with "table footer views" here. OP was asking for the latter.

Comment: This is incorrect, section footers will float on top of the table view.